# C#. WinForms. Связь компонента и формы

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем доброго времени суток.

Есть ссылка на некоторый невизуальный компонент:

```
Component c;
```

Вопрос: как узнать с какой формой/UserControl-ом данный компонент связан?
Свойства Site и Container у этого компонента == null.
Он же создан вместе с какой-то формой, а не сам по себе...

Answer (score 1):

У невизуальных компонент нет ссылки на содержащую их форму, напротив, класс формы инкапсулирует компонент и управляет им.
Компонент действительно связан с формой, но только в том смысле, что является полем её класса.

Comment: С этим согласен, не спорю - в том-то и была задача: "полем какого объекта я являюсь?". Ну, собственно, **для частного случая**, т.к. пишу свою компоненту, то рецепт нашел.

Answer (score 1):

**Если пишем свою компоненту**, то в DesignMode надо перехватить изменение свойства Site (в свое собственное свойство ContainerControl можно собственно и записать ту самую Form/UserControl, "на которую" данный компонент "бросили"):

```
public ContainerControl ContainerControl { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Перегрузка свойства Site.
    /// Цель: в момент Site.set запрашиваем IDesignerHost, а у него уже RootComponent.
    /// </summary>
    public override ISite Site
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Site;
        }
        set
        {
            base.Site = value;
            if (value == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            IDesignerHost host = value.GetService(typeof(IDesignerHost)) as IDesignerHost;
            if (host != null)
            {
                IComponent componentHost = host.RootComponent;
                if (componentHost is ContainerControl)
                {
                    ContainerControl = componentHost as ContainerControl;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Полная версия тут:
[Get Component's Parent Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371464/get-components-parent-form)

**Если используем уже готовый какой-нибудь компонент** - то... да - грусть :(...